# does module.exports simply binds function to an object?

Tags: node.js, express, module, export, ejs

I tried to bind few functions to my `module.exports` object.
I did it like that:

```
module.exports = {func1,func2,func3}
```

but when I saw someone else does it, he did it like that:

```
 module.exports.func1= func1;
 module.exports.func2 = func2 ;
 module.exports.func3 = func3;
```

I started to investigate, tried to log the two ways and got the same object

```
exports: {
    bellBoy: [Function: func1],
    bellBoy2: [Function: func2],
    bellBoy3: [Function: func3]
  }
```

There is a diffrence?
both ways are fine or there is something different happening in the background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two are almost same.
when you use this.

```
module.exports = {func1,func2,func3}
```

you have to import like this.

```
const {funct1,funct2,funct3} = require('./path/to/file');
```

if you use like this

```
 module.exports.func4= func1;
 module.exports.func5 = func2 ;
 module.exports.func6 = func3;
```

you have to import like this:

```
const {funct4,funct5,funct6} = require('./path/to/file');
```

Both are same but when you use first method you have to use the same name wherever you call your function.
But with second method you can use different names.
Hope you get the idea!